# How are those notifications called?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Sometimes in certain apps when you are doing a certain action and there is an error or something , and a gray-ish square (On most phones the square has rounder corners) appears with some text in it (extra info about what happened or something like that) , and i want to know how they are called ? and how to implement them in my app via android studio ?

[You can see an example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCVMA.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is called a Toast message.
The quickest way to create such a message is
`Toast.makeText(this, "Message to show", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Answer (score 2):

It's called Toast. Check its description and usage samples here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html